# Low CPU usage while run pyspark svm model

Tags: pyspark, svm, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to run svm on very very large dataset, which I am unable to run using sklearn. It take endless time with sklearn. So I decided to use pyspark
Here are my spark configurations

```
[('spark.app.id', 'local-1606562652917'),
 ('spark.executor.id', 'driver'),
 ('spark.app.name', 'SVM'),
 ('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '6g'),
 ('spark.driver.port', '60042'),
 ('spark.executor.cores', '6'),
 ('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'),
 ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'),
 ('spark.master', 'local[*]'),
 ('spark.submit.pyFiles', ''),
 ('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'),
 ('spark.driver.host', '192.168.56.1'),
 ('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'true'),
 ('spark.cores.max', '6')]
```

Here is spark session

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('SVM') \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Here is SVM code

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LinearSVC,OneVsRest
clf = OneVsRest(classifier=LinearSVC(labelCol='label', featuresCol='features'))
clf = clf.fit(train)
```

Cpu consumption is less than 10%, when I check via task manager.

Comment: Spark has lazy evaluation and nothing would be computed until you call something like `show()` or `toPandas()`. So there will be no cpu consumption

Comment: so spark would not be fast while fitting svm to data

Comment: No, if you run it properly it will be very fast. Check the spark ML docs for examples. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html

Comment: @mck please consider posting this as an answer

Comment: It will run fast *if you have a cluster*; just running Spark in a single machine will certainly *not* run faster and it is not advised.

Comment: @desertnaut my system has 6 cores, would not it help?

Answer (score 0):

Spark has lazy evaluation and nothing would be computed until you call something like `df.show()` or `df.toPandas()`. So there will be no CPU consumption at all before Spark starts to evaluate things.

As suggested by @desertnaut, for the performance of Spark, it will depend on the hardware that you have, e.g. it will be fast on a cluster but slow on a single machine.